# Set div html to display contents of array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm doing a simple php chat application that sends the message input to the server via ajax and saves it in a text file.  Now after it retrieves all data in the text file and sends it to the client in an array form via ajax.  Now what i want to do is populate a div called "chat-box" with the contents of the array as html but nothing happens and ii don't get any errors in firebug apart from ": undefined".

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // setInterval(function(){alert("Hello");}, 5000);
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function getchat(messages)
                {
                    var chat = $(".chat-box").html();
                    for (var i=0; i < messages.length; i++)
                    {
                        var msg = messages[i].split(':');
                        var name = msg[0];
                        var post = msg[1];
                        $(".chat-box").html(chat + "<div class='bubble'>" + name + " : " + post + "</div>");

                    }
                }

                $("#btnPost").click(function() {
                    var msg = $("#chat-input").val();
                    if (msg.length == 0)
                    {
                        alert ("Enter a message first!");
                        return;
                    }
                    var name = $("#name-input").val();
                    var chat = $(".chat-box").html();
                    //$(".chat-box").html(chat + "<br /><div class='bubble'>" + msg + "</div>");

                    var data = {
                        Name : name,
                        Message : msg
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "chat.php",
                        data: {
                            data: JSON.stringify(data)
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(chat) {
                            getchat(chat)
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: You state that this is a text file that you are trying to display. Change your Ajax datatype from json to text and see if that helps.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data returned by your php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead for updating the chat box:

```
var index = messages[i].indexOf(':');
var name = messages[i].substring(0, index);
var content = messages[i].substring(index + 1);
var $newMessage = $('<div>')
        .addClass('bubble')
        .text(name + " : " + content);
$(".chat-box").append($newMessage);
```

If this doesn't work, check if the messages returned by the server are correct by using `console.log(messages)`.

Answer (score 0):

You said the div is called chat-box. Perhaps it's this:

`$(".chat-box")`

maybe you intended to write it as `$("#chat-box")`